# ggplot r error Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, type-conversion

I have a list as attached.

```
    Site Name  5833             count  ratio
1   Boston     0 days per week  1      0.01428571
2   Boston     1 day per week   6      0.08571429
3   Boston     2 days per week  11     0.15714286
4   Boston     3 days per week  5      0.07142857
5   Seattle    0 days per week  2      0.02857143
6  Seattle     1 day per week   6      0.08571429
7  Seattle     2 days per week  10     0.14285714
8  Seattle     3 days per week  8      0.11428571
```

when I use ggplot - I have to use name <- "5833" since this will be put into for loop later.

```
name <- "5833"
ggplot(com_agg,aes(x=com_agg[,c(name)], y=ratio,fill=`Site Name`))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

I get error:

```
"Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. 
Defaulting to continuous. Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"
```

I noticed the selection of column name for this dataframe have to be included in a pair of backtick automatically in R. it may be due to the space or special name in the columns. so I can't simply use name of column in ggplot.

Comment: do `class(com_agg[,c(name)])`. You should see that it isn't a numeric column, which is what ggplot warns you about.

Comment: Also, passing a *vector* rather than a *column name* inside `aes()` will cause problems in more complex plots. `y = ratio`, is good; re-referencing your data frame with `x = com_agg[, c(name)]` is bad. Best would be to rename your column so it follows standard column name guidelines (doesn't start with a number) and use `x = x5833`.

Answer (score 0):

Even without formally verifying the [**`class`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.2/topics/class) of the variable, from the attached data it is obvious that you are passing string or factor, without looking at class. You can easily convert your variable to numeric by running:

```
com_agg$`5833` <- as.numeric(substr(com_agg$`5833`, 1, 1))
```

In  case of your variable being more complex than in the provided example you may consider looking at the [*`taRfix::desting`*](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/taRifx/versions/1.0.6/topics/destring) or similar functions that would allow you to conveniently handle this minor challenge.

My preference for addressing this problem would involve making use of `dplyr`/`ggplot` pipeline where you could easily apply your transformations without the need to create another object or modify the satate of existing object. For instance:

```
com_agg %>%
    mutate(`5833` = as.numeric(substr(`5833`, 1, 1))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = `5833`, y=ratio, fill =`Site Name`)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

---

It seems that the data frame you  are using was created with `check.names = FALSE`, as in:

```
data.frame("1" = 1, check.names = FALSE)
```

before doing anything I would suggest that you may consider using syntatically correct names, hence **``` `` ```** in the syntax above. You can create syntactically correct names by running:

```
make.names(names(dta))
```

on your data. If you wish, you could introduce the following syntax to your `ggplot` / `dplyr` pipeline:

```
setNames(make.names(names(.)), object = .)
```

This would fix the syntactically incorrect names. For instance `5833` would become `X5833`. I reckon this may make your loops slightly more tedious to write but, on principle, it's worth doing as it would spare you using **``` `` ```** and potential future mishaps with trying to use constant as column name.

Comment: I have to use x=com_agg[,c(name)] in ggplot because this is in a for loop and name is the variable that's passed in each iteration. Even I change the name to X5833 I still have to use x=com_agg[,c(name)] in the loop. so I don't see this can help me out.

Comment: @JamesWang The name thing was a side comment. You could create a name with X by using get/paste combination. The key thing is that you variable is of wrong time and should be converted to numeric as suggested in the beginning.

Comment: @JamesWang that's still the wrong way to use dynamic column names in `ggplot`. The better ways are to use `aes_`, `aes_q`, or `aes_string` (see the documentation of those for examples). The way you have will work for simple plots, but will not ever work for more complicated plots such as  plots with facets or binned data.